# bdb_dn2entry("cn=kerberoskdc,cn=config,dc=example,dc=com") Meaning?

Tags: ldap, openldap, berkeley-db

What is the meaning of third line. I got this message when I run my openldap server while binding a user.

```
entry_decode(cn=user,dc=example,dc=com)
5a3fd996 => bdb_search
5a3fd996 bdb_dn2entry("cn=kerberoskdc,cn=config,dc=example,dc=com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `slapd` requesting its backend to load data corresponding to the distinguished name `"cn=kerberoskdc,cn=config,dc=example,dc=com"`. This happens a lot under the hood when performing ldap opertions, the dn is used as a primary key for fast lookups.

`bdb_dn2entry` is an internal function used by `slapd`'s backend, it is invoked when ldap operations are performed (you should be able to see which operation triggers the call in the log file where this line appears).

> Openldap uses a backend for a normal slapd database. Backends do the
>   actual work of storing or retrieving data in response to LDAP
>   requests. Backends may be compiled statically into slapd, or when
>   module support is enabled, they may be dynamically loaded.
>
> OpenLDAP's `bdb` abd `hdb` backends use the Oracle Berkeley DB (BDB)
>   package to store data.

`bdb_dn2entry` is a function that actually retrieve data from the database. It is shared with other ldap's backend (not only for bdb/hdb) as it is defined as a function prototype in the header file [proto-bdb.h](https://github.com/delphij/openldap/blob/master/servers/slapd/back-bdb/proto-bdb.h) in the source code :

```c
/**
 * dn2entry.c
 */
#define bdb_dn2entry                BDB_SYMBOL(dn2entry)

int bdb_dn2entry LDAP_P(( Operation *op, DB_TXN *tid,
    struct berval *dn, EntryInfo **e, int matched,
    DB_LOCK *lock ));
```

The real action takes place in [dn2entry.c](https://github.com/delphij/openldap/blob/master/servers/slapd/back-bdb/dn2entry.c) :

`dn2entry` looks up the `dn` in the cache/indexes and returns the corresponding entry. If the requested DN is not found and `matched` is `TRUE`, it returns info for the closest ancestor of the DN. Otherwise `EntryInfo  e` is `NULL`.

Comment: EricLavault..Thank you for the detailed answer. I got that message while performing this operation `con.auth 'cn=user,dc=example,dc=com', 'user'`. Could you tell me why different dn is triggered when the dn I mentioned is diffferent.

Comment: @Praneetha Sorry for the late reply. It seems you have a config that set Kerberos as a 'master' authentication system (hence the `cn=kerberoskdc` part). So I think every time you authenticate a user through ldap, the server first handles the request - as usual using `bind dn` to authenticate the request, then on success it loads the corresponding entry to get authorization data for that user, then (**!Assumption!**) it reads a _kdc_ entry to be able to delegate the authentication to the KDC. You might want to check the [Kerberos Documentation](http://kerberos.org/docs/index.html).